# Excel VBA to Run and Export Access Queries

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I have the following code that kicks off a series of queries in an Access database from Excel.  When these queries are run by themselves in Access, they work fine and succeed in generating the right file, but when I convert the macros to run in Excel using a button click, I run into some problems.  See my code below:

```
Sub AccessImport()

Dim acApp As Object
Dim MyDatabase As String
Dim question As String

question = MsgBox(Prompt:="Are you sure you want to complete this action?  Running this process is lengthy and could take a couple minutes to complete.", Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Run SOD Matrix")

If question = vbYes Then

MyDatabase = "directory string"
OutputFile = "output string"

    'open the database and apend the combination table to existing
    Set acApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
        acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase (MyDatabase)
        acApp.Visible = True
        acApp.UserControl = True
        acApp.DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        acApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "QRYDELETE_PS_ROLE_NAMES", acViewNormal, acEdit
        acApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "QRYDELETE_PS_ROLE_USER", acViewNormal, acEdit
        acApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "QRYDELETE_SOD_TBL", acViewNormal, acEdit
        acApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "QRYAPPEND_PS_ROLE_NAMES", acViewNormal, acEdit
        acApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "QRYAPPEND_PS_ROLE_USER", acViewNormal, acEdit
        acApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "QRYAPPEND_SOD_TBL", acViewNormal, acEdit
        'acApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "QRY_HIGH", acViewNormal, acEdit
        acApp.DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "QRY_HIGH", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", OutputFile, _
            False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
        acApp.DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        acApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
        acApp.Quit
    Set acApp = Nothing

Else
MsgBox ("Process has been cancelled.")
    Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox ("Process has completed successfully.")
End Sub
```

For the last query, meant to export and save the output, I run into an error telling me `Property is not found.`  I've tried changing the `DoCmd` to `TransferSpreadsheet`, the format type of `acFormalXLS` to prevent conversion issues, but I still cannot get it to complete successfully.  Do I need to put this code in a module instead of keeping it on the sheet itself?  Thoughts/help?

Comment: I don't work with access but I can make it out that you are latebinding with access. In such a case have you declared the ACCESS Constants? `Const acOutputQuery As Long = 1` and `Const acExportQualityPrint as Long = 0`

Comment: I have not, didn't even know to do that.  Why would I need to do those things?  Just for my own education....

I did find a work-around that was successful.  I decided to string these queries together inside an Access macro and run it using acApp.DoCmd.RunMacro.  That succeeded in doing everything I really wanted, so it was a different direction I took but achieved the right end.

Comment: `acOutputQuery` and `acExportQualityPrint` are ACCESS Constants. Excel will not understand them. Put the code that I gave in the comment above at the very top of your code.

Comment: Did they make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siddharth identified the issue with this statement:

```vb
acApp.DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "QRY_HIGH", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", OutputFile, _
    False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
```

Without a reference to the Access object library, Excel will know nothing about the Access constants `acOutputQuery` and `acExportQualityPrint`.

You would be wise to add `Option Explict` to the module's Declarations section and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  When you do that, I suspect you will discover similar problems with the lines such as this ...

```vb
acApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "QRYDELETE_PS_ROLE_NAMES", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

Excel will also know nothing about the Access constants `acViewNormal` and `acEdit`.  However, if your intent was to execute "action" queries (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc), it's good that those constants are unrecognized.  Otherwise you would be opening those queries in Design View instead of executing them.

Consider a different approach ...

```vb
Const dbFailOnError As Long = 128
'acApp.DoCmd.SetWarnings False ' leave SetWarnings on!
acApp.CurrentDb.Execute "QRYDELETE_PS_ROLE_NAMES", dbFailOnError
acApp.CurrentDb.Execute "QRYDELETE_PS_ROLE_USER", dbFailOnError
```